# Infinitive vs. "ing" + past particle

Tags: infinitives, past-participles

> Among the earliest telescopes were Galilean telescopes, modeled after the simple instruments built by Galileo, the first person having used telescopes to study the stars and planets.

I know "having used" should be changed to "to have." Could someone point out the rule or reasoning behind this?

Comment: My "reasoning" is you're right that *having used* is wrong, but I can't see any reason to replace it by *to have*. What's wrong with just *...Galileo, the first person **to use** telescopes...*?

Answer (score 1):

My old school grammar says:

A to-infinitive follows after the first/the last, the only, the few and after superlatives.

The infinitive expresses what has happened or will happen. The infinitive stands for a relative clause.

Unfortunatately I have no idea why English in theses cases prefers the infinitive construction instead of a relative clause. Of course, the infinitive is a little bit shorter but I think a relative clause is acceptable, too.

Examples

1 We were the first to enter (= who entered) the exhibition that day and

2 the last to leave.

3 You are not the only person to have been there (= who has been there).

4 This is the biggest exhibition to have taken place here since 1938.

Source: Grundzüge der englischen Grammatik, Klett Verlag, 1972.

Comment: Then again, "having used a telescope" would be grammatical to start a sentence.

Comment: You are right. Such a participle clause refers to the following subject.

Comment: To-infinitive (a subset of non-finite) clauses can also be used after nouns. 'And you are the man to do that, I suppose?' I suppose that 'who is going' is deleted here. Again, there is the sense of specialness, uniqueness.